# How to replace the handlebars with htmlbars in Ember CLI app?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, handlebars.js, htmlbars

I am facing the following issue after upgrading the Ember and Ember data to the canary versions.

```
Cannot set property 'compilerInfo' of undefined
```

I found the discussion about the issue in Ember CLI repo.

https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/2955

The solution is to replace handlebars with htmlbars. But I don't know the exact steps to do that.

I checked [handlebars](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-htmlbars) repo. It gives code snippets but I don't know where to place the code exactly.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will still be using Handlebars, but you need 2.0.

For HTMLBars, what you'll change is the template compiler.

```
npm uninstall --save-dev broccoli-ember-hbs-template-compiler
npm install --save-dev ember-cli-htmlbars
rm -rf bower_components
bower install --save handlebars#2.0.0
bower install
```

Comment: But I did not installed handlbars#2.0.0